# I'm restricted to using framework 3.5 because I'm writting a SQL CLR for SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql, tfs, clr

I'm restricted to using framework 3.5 because I'm writting a SQL CLR for SQL Server 2008 R2.  Visual Studio 2013 uses Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common fro framwork 4.5.  Is there a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common for framework 3.5?  If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

The Team Foundation Server assemblies are bound to specific versions of Visual Studio (simply put). So you'll have to find a Visual Studio version that shipped with .NET 3.5 - Visual Studio 2010, i.e. TFS 2010. However, then you'll have to make sure that this TFS version is still compatible with the TFS Server you'll want to contact (or the TFS workspaces you'll want to work with).

Then, having arbitrary assemblies in SQL Server is also something you'll probably want to avoid.

Possibly, it would be better to have a standalone service, that uses whatever TFS assemblies you need, and have your SQL Server .NET code talk with that via HTTP, etc.

That way you can decouple the (.NET) versions.

Finally, it would be helpful if you tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.